# Android Transparency bug? android:color/transparent

Tags: android, transparency

Random bug on mostly > 4.0 devices

Sometimes transparency that is set in .xml files is shown as white/light grey shade.
This happens for practically everything , TextView , ImageView , Button , Relative Layout...

Has anyone experienced this before ?

All I can find is a transparency bug in Jelly Bean that happens with secondary accounts , which isn't related to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, but was able to work around the problem by using the 8-digit color code in which the first two digits represent the transparency level (00 being fully transparent, FF being fully opaque).

Using #00000000 results in a fully transparent color and can be used as a direct replacement for android:color/transparent.